# Google/search engine links to Drupal site broken, why is domain missing a slash?

Tags: 7, uri

I noticed that links to my site from search engines don't work. Google links me to `https://www.site.comcontent/page-title-1`. I am using Pathauto and Clean URLs. The slash is missing at the end of the domain. Is there something obvious I have misconfigured? I can navigate around my site just fine once I am there.

Edit: originally mis-typed the problem - note https instead of http.

Comment: Do you have the metatag or global redirect modules add a canonical url metatag to your page?

Comment: @ShawnConn No, I have neither of those modules enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a problem introduced with the freshly installed SSL cert and redirecting to https, in combination with using Clean URLs. Turns out there is [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/https-information) on configuring Clean URLs and HTTPS with Apache.

Comment: SSL cert? Is it kind of module that changes the URL's?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the edit page of the node and check for the url of the node. There are chances that you have overridden the path of the node.

So instead of using pattern from path auto you might have manually added that url.

I actually am curious to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing search engines to think those are valid URLs. Google/Bing are pretty vigilant about not display 404 links to users, so they are getting those bad URLs from somewhere. The solution probably isn't Drupal-centric unless it's supplying these bad URLs to search engines.

Try using search engine tools like [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) & [Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster) to find the source. You should also look at the [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module to supply search engines your valid URLs and a module like [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) & [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) to make sure your site is sending out canonical URL sources that will be used in search results.